# SKMap (Skobbler) convert map data

Tags: android, maps, skmaps

How can I convert the map data from Navitel to .skm and use it offline in my android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot do this on your own.

An intermediary step would be to convert your data to .osm (something our map conversion tool understands) and then we could create an .skm file. Note: currently, the tool that allows one to convert a custom .osm file to .skm is not public (depending on your project scale, we might be able to convert it under an enterprise agreement - send an email to dev@skobbler.com).